# HttpContext always returns null

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am having an issue with HttpContext always returning null.  I have pasting my code below. I have looked for a solution online and although there are plenty of examples of exactly what I am trying to do, I haven't been able to resolve it. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what else might be causing this?

```
public class DatabaseTenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{
    private Guid _tenantId;

    public DatabaseTenantProvider(TenantContext context, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        //this is always null
        var host = accessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;

         _tenantId = context.GetTenantId(host);
    }
}
```

In my startup class, I have...

```
 services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: Where do you access `DatabaseTenantProvider` class?

Comment: From my main context.

modelBuilder.Entity<Video>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.TenantId == _tenantProvider.GetTenantId());

Basically I am trying to implement a Multi tenancy solution with separate databases. I'm using this set of  tutorials to guide me.

http://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/tenant-providers/

Comment: Are you calling `DbContext` from background thread?

Comment: I am injecting DatabaseTenantProvider into my main database context so I can get the current tenantId. I have a second database context named "TenantsContext" that is injected into the DatabaseTenantProvider class. 
The "TenantsContext" contains the  method "GetTenantId" that takes the host and uses it to query the database and find the tenant id associated with 
the current host header. My problem is the HttpContext is always null (when I try to access it in my DatabaseTenantProvider class - as shown above) meaning I cannot get the hostheader to pass to the GetTenantId method.

Comment: Can anyone else help me resolve this issue?

Comment: based on the linked tutorial, I think you need to make sure you inject your dbcontexts as scoped so they are created once per web request. If you are injecting them as singleton that would cause the problem

Comment: I am injecting them as scoped.

Comment: Still no dice with this one.

Comment: Ok I figured out what was causing this issue. I am going to post it as the answer, so anyone else who has this issue can clearly see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling a method in my DbInitializer class, which creates and seeds the database if it doesn't already exist and/or is not populated with data. I was passing both of my database contexts to this method as follows.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {

                var context = services.GetRequiredService<PrimaryContext>();
                var tenantContext = services.GetRequiredService<SecondaryContext>();
                DbInitializer.Initialize(primaryContext, secondaryContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }
```

Calling the GetRequiredService method to pass the contexts to the Initialize method was causing the IHttpContextAccessor to return null in my DatabaseTenantProvider class. I'm not fully clear on why this was happening, so I would really appreciate it if someone could explain/clarify in a comment below.

Comment: I have similar problem too :(

Answer (score 0):

You should not use IHttpContextAccessor in the constructor of your class. You should keep that around and use it to get the tenant id like this:

```
public class DatabaseTenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{
    public DatabaseTenantProvider(TenantContext context, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = accessor; 
    }

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public Guid GetTenantId(TenantContext context)
    {
        var host = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
        return context.GetTenantId(host);
     }
}
```

Comment: I have also tried that because that is what most of the examples recommend. However, it still returns null.

Comment: definitely should not use HttpContextAccessor in your constructor in any case. You must keep it around and use it at the last possible moment to resolve your tenant so that there is a web request at the time it is resolved. This is especially important if you are injecting DatabaseTenantProvider as a Singleton. I can tell you I have [already solved multi-tenancy](https://www.cloudscribe.com/docs/multi-tenant-support) in my [open source project ](https://www.cloudscribe.com/)

Comment: I definitely will.  Thank you.